# Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result

Tags: php, arrays, mysqli

I'm about to open my website when I noticed that one of my mods gives me this error:

> Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in /var/www/vbsubscribetouser.php on line 303

I've went to line 303 and this is what I found:

```
//Check if requested username can be followed.
if (in_array($followingdata['usergroupid'], explode("|", $vbulletin->options['subscribetouser_usergroups_cannot']))){
```

Here is all the code starting at line 303:

```
//Check if requested username can be followed.
if (in_array($followingdata['usergroupid'], explode("|", $vbulletin->options['subscribetouser_usergroups_cannot']))){
    exit;
}

if ($followinginfo[subscribers] > 0){
    $user_followers = $followinginfo[followers].$userinfo[userid].'|';
}
else{
    $user_followers = '|'.$userinfo[userid].'|';
}

$vbulletin->db->query_write("
    UPDATE " . TABLE_PREFIX . "user
    SET subscribers = subscribers + 1, `followers` = '$user_followers'
    WHERE userid = $followinginfo[userid]
");
```

I'm not an expert in php coding, so a bit of help would be great before opening the website. Any help/suggestions?

Thank you very much!

Answer (score 35, accepted):

> Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Use [`mysqli_fetch_assoc`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php) or [`mysqli_fetch_array`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) to fetch a result row as an associative array.

```
$query = "SELECT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$followingdata = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

or

```
$followingdata = $result->fetch_array(MYSQLI_ASSOC);
```