# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array

Tags: mysqli

I found the line where this problem is, but I don't know what to do with it since I'm not that advanced yet... It's the first line here, can you help me with this, please?

```
$loginname=$query['username'];
$$info1="upload/".$loginname."/sth1.txt";
$$info2="upload/".$loginname."/sth2.txt";
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fatal error: Cannot use object of type mysqli\_result](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525413/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-mysqli-result)

Answer (score 0):

Where is your `mysqli` object. Post that code