# What does Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array mean?

Tags: php

I am trying to find the last teacher id from my database and getting this error. **Fatal error:  Cannot use object of type mysqli_result as array in** .My Codes are as follows. Any Help ?

```
class tinyteacher {
public function getLastTeacherId(){
  $query = ("SELECT `teacherid` FROM `teacher` ORDER BY `teacherid` DESC ");
  $result = $this->db->select($query);
  return $result;
 }
}

<div class="col-sm-6">
  <input type="text" name="teacherid" value="
  <?php 
    $teacher = new tinyteacher();
    $lastteacher = $teacher->getLastTeacherId();
   echo $lastteacher;   
  ?> 
</div>
```

Comment: If you run the same query in an SQL tool, what happens, does it return a result or nothing?

Comment: I'm not seeing that method in a class. Is it really in a class and you're just showing us wack code? `return $result->fetch_object()` then access as an Object?

Comment: this method in a class. I did not type it here... because i thought this would shorten my code.

Comment: My apologies, for not being a mind reader.

Comment: Code edited, now you can see the class.

Answer (score 0):

your `function return $result; array object`

and you `print array object` in `echo` `echo use for print string not for array`

so use `print_r` instead of `echo`

like `print_r($lastteacher);`

Answer (score 0):

Can't use object of type `mysqli_result` as `array`

> Use `mysqli_fetch_assoc` or `mysqli_fetch_array` to fetch a result row
>   as an associative array.

```
$query = "SELECT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data_array = $result->fetch_assoc()
```

and [for more reference click here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525413/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-mysqli-result)

Comment: you copy from here:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16525413/fatal-error-cannot-use-object-of-type-mysqli-result

Comment: write your own answer not copy another user answer

Comment: I think this site for help not for the allegations.  And yes I copied but not say this is my code. I share because he needed, thanks for your folks up @Bhargav.

Comment: but you paste refrence also or link of this answer in comment boy wake up

Comment: `$mysqli = mysqli_connect("host","user","password","your_db");
$query = "SELECT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($query);
$data_array = $result->fetch_assoc()` use your parameters for connection.